# Centering buttons dynamically as added with bootstrap

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using angular bootstrap.  At the top of our page we have a section that will be used for various control dropdowns.  I want to have a 3-4 dropdowns with ng-if on them, having the appear or disappear depending on rather or not a given page allows the functionality of the dropdowns.

I would like these dropdowns to be centered.  I may define btn 1, 2, 3, and 4 in order, but if only btn 3 and btn 4 are active they should show on the middle of the page, not on the right side.  In other words if a dropdowns is disabled due to the ng-if argument the visible dropdowns should center align as if the other's never existed.  Each dropdowns should be a standard width, so that I'm confident that all dropdowns will fit on a single row if all were active.

I'm having a horrible time getting this done, despite feeling that it should be trivially simple behavior.  I've tried pagnation-centered, but it didn't seem to do anything.  I've tried placing them in button groups, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

Can someone point me to the appropriate bootstrap classes to make this work?

Comment: Did you try with class `center-block`?

Comment: @rpadovani I did without any luck, however, I'm quite a novice at CSS anything, so I can't exclude the possibility I was doing it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure thing, take this CSS/HTML as example:

CSS

```
.form-inline .form-control.w140{
     width:120px; 
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <form class="form-inline text-center">
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control w140">
            <option>foo</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control w140">
            <option>foo</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control w140">
            <option>foo</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <select class="form-control w140">
            <option>foo</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `text-center` class centers them, regardless of how many `<div class="form-group">` there are.

See [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9d1vjzd8/)

Comment: Is there a way to get this to work without defining a special width in my CSS, were trying to depend entirely on bootstrap as much as possible.  It looks like I'm suppose to be able to use form-control col-sm-x, but it doesn't seem to work for me?